# Free *regular* application on iPhone - how to display ads?

Tags: iphone

What ad networks are available to iPhone developers who want to distribute free regular apps (not web applets) that are ad supported?

[Prompted by this story on crappy app making $200/hr.](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/09/01/22/iphone_developer_app_store_rewards_crap_apps.html)

Comment: This is marketing, not programming.

Comment: I think "How do I display ads in my app?" is a valid programming/development question.

Comment: Not only do I agree that this is a valid question for SO, but I'm curious to see the answers. I've had a few networks contact me for advertising in my iPhone app, but none seemed to have any high-quality advertisers. It's a very young market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one:

- [Pinch Media](http://www.pinchmedia.com/)

I'm making this Community Wiki so anyone can add to this list.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a Tower Defense game (TapDefense) that makes the user click a link to a paid app in order to save the game.  It uses AdMob as its ad distributor.

Comment: AdMob is also the distributor for the "crappy" app cited in the article

Answer (score 1):

[The Deck](http://decknetwork.net/) prides itself on being a very "high quality" advertising network. I've seen them on a few iPhone apps, but they're apparently picky about who they will allow to run their ads.

Comment: Yes, The Deck is an excellent, mature ad network, but is invite-only.