# Show ads in iphone application. Is iAds the only way or there is another alternative?

Tags: iphone, ads

I want to show ads in my iPhone application. i can do it using iAds. I need more details regarding this.

My first question is: is iAd mandatory if i have to show advertisement in my iphone application? or i am allowed to use some other alternative to display ads.

will iAds work in earlier versions of iPhone ?

can i test iAds outside USA ?

Apple takes 40% when we use iAds, is there any other alternative? so, we don't have to share 40% of the amount every time ?

I hope, i wrote everything in the way its easy to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off topic for this website, and honestly, not hard to find an answer if you can use Google. Or Bing, even.

Comment: this has been answered before on this site too.

Comment: @benzado - thanks for your response. i've tried Google, bing etc. already. Didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @progrmr - If this question has been answered before on this site. It would be great if u can post the url/link of the page. so, i can look at the solution.

Comment: @benzado - Its not off the topic. I have to display advertisements in my iPhone app. if i use iAds, apple takes 40% straight away. So, i want to find a solution for it.

Comment: @progrmr - i found the page where its already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470852/free-regular-application-on-iphone-how-to-display-ads
thanks

Comment: @vikasone - I didn't have time earlier, but here is a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148686/available-most-profitable-ad-system-for-iphone-app/7148748#7148748) that was on SO recently.

Comment: @progrmr - thanks. Got much better answer from the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random google search turns up at least 10 other ad networks:

1. AdMob
2. Brightroll
3. Google AdSense for Mobile Applications
4. Greystripe
5. InMobi
6. Jumptap
7. MdotM
8. Millennial Media
9. SAY Media [VideoEgg]
10. ZestADZ

and at least one meta ad engine that combines all of the others [here](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/ios/AdWhirliOSSDKSetup.html).

I have no idea which ones are good, though.

Comment: Thanks.

Here is the answer i was looking for :

Apple told us last week that it would not prevent third-party ad networks from embedding ads in applications for the iPad, iPhone and iPod Touch, even though those networks would compete with its own iAd platform.

“Yes, we still allow developers or other advertising companies to serve ads within their apps,” Apple spokeswoman Trudy Muller told